# Legal term for a document of done job

Tags: legalese

What is the name of a document that parties sign when job by one party is done and second party agrees to accept it?

Comment: [Final Acceptance Certificate (FAC)](https://www.theprojectdefinition.com/final-acceptance-certificate-fac/)

Answer (score 1):

This is frequently called a "Letter of Acceptance".